# php compare array keys, not values

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I am successfully using the array_key_exists(), as described by php.net

Example:

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

But, take out the values, and it doesn't work.

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first', 'second');
if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
?>
```

Not sure how to only compare 2 arrays by their keys only.

Comment: What do yo mean by "compare 2 arrays by their keys only"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first example is an associative array: keys with values assigned. The second example is just a prettier way of saying:

```
array(0 => 'first', 1 => 'second')
```

For the second, you would need to use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array). You shouldn't check for the presence of a key, which `array_key_exists` does, but rather the presence of a value, which `in_array` does.

```
if(in_array('first', $array))
```

Answer (score 5):

In PHP, each element in a array has two parts: the *key* and the *value*.

Unless you manually say what keys you want attached to each value, PHP gives each element a numerical index starting at 0, incrementing by 1.

So the difference between

```
array('first','second')
```

and

```
array('first'=>1,'second'=>4)
```

is that the first doesn't have user-defined keys. (It actually has the keys 0 and 1)

If you were to do `print_r()` on the first, it would say something like

```
Array {
    [0] => "first",
    [1] => "second"
}
```

whereas the second would look like

```
Array {
    ["first"]  => 1,
    ["second"] => 2
}
```

So, to check if the **key** "first" exists, you would use

```
array_key_exists('first',$search_array);
```

to check if the the **value** "first" exists, you would use

```
in_array('first',$search_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the second example, you didn't assign array keys - you just set up a basic "list" of objects

use `in_array("first", $search_array);` to check if a value is in a regular array

Answer (score 0):

In your second example the keys are numeric your `$search_array` actually looks like this:

```
array(0=>'first', 1=>'second');
```

so they `key` 'first' doesnt exist, the `value` 'first' does. so

```
in_array('first', $search_array);
```

is the function you would want to use.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, if you are not giving key to array element they take default key value.Here you arrray will be internally as bellow

```
 $search_array = array(0=>'first', 1=>'second');
```

Anyway you can still fix this problem by using the array_flip function as below.

```
$search_array = array('first', 'second');
if (array_key_exists('first', array_flip($search_array))) {
    echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
}
```