# Compare the array keys from one array to another array

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a function in php that would able to compare the array keys from another array and return the arrays that doesn't exist on the other array for example:

```
$sample1 = array('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');
$sample2 = array('val1'=>'test','val4'=>'uhm...');
```

If I compare this two arrays I must able to identify that in sample2 variable the 2 associative array indexes val2 and val3 doesn't exist if when I try to base the results coming from sample1 variable.

Are there any functions in php that could do this?

Comment: This post should answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917243/php-compare-array-keys-not-values

Comment: Thanks for the link the array_key_exists really works for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a php function called array_diff_key:

```
<?php
$sample1 = array('val1'=>'char lang', 'val2'=>'wew ambot', 'val3'=>'aw', 'val4'=>'testing lang');
$sample2 = array('val1'=>'test','val4'=>'uhm...');
$difference = array_diff_key($sample1, $sample2);
//print_r($difference); would display val2, val3
?>
```

[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

Comment: thanks this is really a great function it compares associative keys for 2 associative arrays and returns the difference in array datatype but I updated the post I just made a mistake the other one is actually a one dimensional array the array_key_exists did worked for me. :)